# Excel VBA: Is there a way to iterate through characters in a specific range?

Tags: excel, string, vba, iteration

Is there a way to iterate through characters in a specific range, like:

```
...
For each char1 in range1.Characters
    [It does not work the fake code above, because Characters is not a collection]
```

I mean: is there such a collection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to loop to iterate through a single-cell `Range` object containing text, returning single-`Characters` objects, this is one way:

```
Sub IterateCharactersObject()
    Dim ch As Characters, n As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        For n = 1 To .Characters.Count
            Set ch = .Characters(n, 1)
            'print position#, character, font name & size to immediate window
            Debug.Print "#" & n & "=" & ch.Text, ch.Font.Name, ch.Font.Size
        Next n
    End With
End Sub
```

> The `Characters` method is necessary only when you need to change some of an object's text without affecting the rest (you cannot use the `Characters` method to format a portion of the text if the object doesn't support rich text). To change all the text at the same time, you can usually apply the appropriate method or property directly to the object.

...or if you didn't actually need to return a `Characters` object, it may be better to do it using the `MID` and `LEN` functions:

```
Sub IterateCharacters_String()
    Dim n As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        For n = 1 To Len(.Value)
            'print position# and character to immediate window
            Debug.Print "#" & n & "=" & Mid(.Value, n, 1)
        Next n
    End With
End Sub
```

This could also be accomplished without VBA using the `MID` and `LEN` worksheet functions.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**Characters Object** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/characters-object-excel)
- MSDN : [**Range.Characters Property** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-characters-property-excel)
- MSDN : [**Mid Function** (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/mid-function)
- MSDN : [**MID Function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mid-function-427e6895-822c-44ee-b34a-564a28f2532c)

Comment: I would introduce a variable to store length of text outside the loop: `myLen = Len(.Value)`. Due to constantly reading from range it takes a while if there are many repetitions. With an empty inside of the loop, on Cell A1 containing text "ashleedawg" the difference has been 0.06 sec vs 1.16 sec for 1 mln iterations. For performance obviously `.Value` should be stored outside as string in similar fashion.